# SELECT one column if the other is null

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to select value in a2 if it's there, but if it's NULL I want to select value in b2

requested question

`=query(A:B, "select B where A is null OR select B)`

output obtained from @player0

=INDEX(IF(A:A="", B:B, A:A))

need to modify with index match

How to use INDEX MATCH along with this

any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A=""; B:B; A:A))
```

Comment: many thanks . 

if i wanted to use this with #importrange function 

=IFERROR(INDEX(IF(IMPORTRANGE("sheet url","sheet!A:A")="",
IMPORTRANGE("sheet url","sheet!B:B"),IMPORTRANGE("sheet url","sheet!A:A"")

i tried with this i only got a blank output

Comment: @iRFAAN possible, but first you need to run simple `=IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "sheet!A1")` to connect your sheets by allowing access

Comment: But how to use match inside ( i mean index match) when i tried it has given a "FALSE" Output

Comment: @iRFAAN share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: this is the sheet to take data to obtain the output

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKFMnGhkjPaLAGoVacpS0wos7stlYgenbZtkwHyW5Z0/edit?usp=sharing

Output will be like the below sheet and the data will be obtained from above

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ym3nthL03nRa6iELC1rUsFavJdQa1yu1U5kO-DT40Xg/edit#gid=0

Comment: @iRFAAN https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJlJa.png

Comment: please check the https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ym3nthL03nRa6iELC1rUsFavJdQa1yu1U5kO-DT40Xg/edit#gid=0

Comment: @iRFAAN see the pink cell